# Returning specific values dependent on the email entered 

Tags: php, function

I have a function that tells me if an email is in or not in the database.  What I would like to know if it is found how could I also pass the variables like `id,name etc` along with it for the particular email that has been found in the DB.

```
function candidateInsert()
{

  if($this->checkEmail($email))
  {
    echo 'found in db';
    echo $email['id'];

  }else{
    echo 'error';
  }
}

function checkEmail($email)
{
     $email = $POST('Email');

    if($email)
    {
        $candemail ="SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE email=?",$email"";

        if(isset($candemail['email']))
        {
                return TRUE;
        } else {
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the insert function you can just do `if($this->check($email))`

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: @RPM That works fine but how could I pass the variables?

Comment: either set them as variables within the class or pass the variables as arguments to the function.

Comment: @Hamish  I have re worded the question

Comment: @RPM Can I please have an example?

Comment: @JessMcKenzie umm, is that all your code?

Comment: @xdazz For this particular section yes

Comment: Unrelated, but `$POST('Email')` should probably be something like `$_POST['email']`

Comment: @BradKoch yes it was only an example

Comment: Also Jess, your title is quite confusing.  Perhaps you should consider changing it to something more relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to echo something of the mail, you need to return the values from CheckMail() function, as like this:

```
function candidateInsert() {
    $newmail = $this->checkEmail($email);

    if($newmail != FALSE ) {
        echo 'found in db';
        echo $newmail['id'];

     }else{
        echo 'error';
     }
}

function checkEmail($email)
{
    $email = $POST('Email');

    if($email)
    {
        $candemail ="SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE email=?",$email"";
        $result = result($candemail ) // Don't know which sql functions u use

        if(isset($result['email'])) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tom,  My $candemail is `Jojo::selectRow("SELECT * FROM {refocus_candidate} WHERE email=?",$email)` see http://www.jojocms.org/docs/jojo-class/#wikiheading_2

Comment: Returns an array = `Array ( [id] => 4 [first_name] =>`

Comment: So does it return values correctly? Can you work it from there yourself? If no, little more info on what it is supposed to do would be appericated

Comment: Tom I have just fixed it I returned $candemail instead of result

Comment: nice! can you edit my answer to be correct, so anybody in future will have correct answer at their hand right away ^^

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that aside from boolean value, you also want to return the id and name. In this case, pass parameters by reference:

```
function candidateInsert()
{  
      $id = "";
      $name;

  if($this->checkEmail($email, $id, $name))
  {
    echo 'found in db';
    echo $id;
    echo $name;

  }else{
    echo 'error';
  }
}

function checkEmail($email, &$id, &$name)
{
     $email = $POST('Email');

    if($email)
    {
        $candemail ="SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE email=?",$email"";

        if(isset($candemail['email']))
        {
                      $id = $candemail['id'];
                      $name = $candemail['name'];
                return TRUE;
        } else {
                return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

By adding & at the beginning of the parameter, you can edit the content of the variables  you pass as argument.

Comment: I think he wants to return id and name too aside from a boolean value.

Comment: you're missing the user input value of email